# Can deadlock be ABSOLUTELY guaranteed in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know I can create a Java code which is VERY likely to deadlock. There are many ready examples which, when run, will provide a deadlock almost instantly.

However, I'm wondering if it's theoretically possible to write a Java code which absolutely guarantees a deadlock?

That is, by analyzing such code one can *prove* there will be a deadlock?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what leads to a deadlock? Thread 1 locks resource one, Thread 2 locks resource 2, thread 1 tries to lock resource two, Thread 2 tries to lock resource 1. Here is a way to guarantee this situation:

1. Thread 1 locks resource 1
2. Thread 1 sets flag FLAG
3. Thread 1 spawns Thread 2
4. Thread 1 waits for FLAG to be reset by Thread 2 (in while loop, for example). We can't use a lock here because we can't distinguish between a lock that has not been used already and one that has been used and was released (as far as i know)
5. Thread 2 locks resource 2
6. Thread 2 resets FLAG
7. Thread 2 tries to lock resource 1
8. Thread 1 resumes, and tries to lock resource 2

=> voila, Deadlock
I guess you can turn this into code yourself (FLAG should be volatile imho)